# How to set pan property like AVAudioPlayer in AVPlayer

Tags: iphone, objective-c

I am using `AVPlayer` to play simultaneously two songs.I have just finished everything using `AVPlayer` ..now my problem is how to set voice for left and Right ears in `AVPlayer`.I want same property as `AVAudioPlayer's` pan property.When we set pan= -0.1 it routes only through Left ear and +1.0 routes to right ear of Headphone.Any help how to do this ?

Comment: Hello, Did you figured it out?

Answer (score -4):

Please check the documentation of AVAudioPlayer and use the pan property but openAL allows pan, gain, location, and balance, along with effects. 
[Playing Sounds with Positioning Using OpenAL](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/AudioVideo/Conceptual/MultimediaPG/UsingAudio/UsingAudio.html)
To provide full-featured audio playback including stereo positioning, level control, and simultaneous sounds, use OpenAL. See “Playing Sounds with Positioning Using OpenAL.”

and check this link
[ObjectAL for iPhone](http://kstenerud.github.com/ObjectAL-for-iPhone/documentation/)

Hope it helps.

Comment: But i am playing audio from Library,does OpenAL supports that ?

Comment: OpenAL (ALSource, or effects in OALSimpleAudio) and AVAudioPlayer (OALAudioTrack, or background audio in OALSimpleAudio) are playback technologies built for different purposes. OpenAL is designed for game-style short sound effects that have no playback delay. AVAudioPlayer is designed for music playback. You can of course mix and match as you please.